# Can't compile code using Boost graphviz.hpp

Tags: boost, graphviz

I'm trying to use read_graphviz extension to pull a graphviz .dot file into a Boost Grpah.  Here is my sample.  I can't get it to compile.  I posted the g++ error message after the code but I had to but it short, it's too long to post here without significant re-formatting.

The documentation the graphviz.hpp library is too terse to guide me in the right direction.  Anyone have any thoughts?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/property_map.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  assert( argc == 2 );

  std::ifstream dotFile( argv[1], std::ifstream::in );

  typedef boost::adjacency_list<> Graph;
  Graph graph( 17 );  

  boost::dynamic_properties properties;
  boost::property_map< Graph, boost::vertex_name_t >::type name = get( boost::vertex_name, graph );
  properties.property( "node_id", name );

  bool readResult;
  readResult = read_graphviz( dotFile, graph, properties );
  return 0;
```

---

```
g++   -Wall   -c -o graphvizTest.o graphvizTest.cpp
/usr/include/boost/dynamic_property_map.hpp: In member function 
std::string boost::detail::dynamic_property_map_adaptor<PropertyMap>::get_string(const boost::any&) 
[with PropertyMap = 
 boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_property_map<
  boost::adjacency_list<
   boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, 
   boost::no_property, boost::no_property, 
   boost::no_property, boost::listS
  >,
  boost::adjacency_list<
   boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, 
   boost::no_property, boost::no_property, boost::listS
  >*, 
  boost::detail::error_property_not_found, 
  boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, 
  boost::vertex_name_t
 >
]':     
graphvizTest.cpp:29:   instantiated from here    
/usr/include/boost/dynamic_property_map.hpp:196: error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'out << boost::get 
[with 
PropertyMap = 
 boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_property_map<
  boost::adjacency_list<
   boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, boost::no_property, 
   boost::no_property, boost::listS
  >, 
  boost::adjacency_list<
   boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, boost::no_property, 
   boost::no_property, boost::listS
  >*, 
  boost::detail::error_property_not_found, 
  boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, 
  boost::vertex_name_t
 >, 
Reference = boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, K = long unsigned int
]

...
```

Comment: You didn't include line 29 of graphvizTest.cpp....

Comment: I cleaned up the code when I submitted the question and removed a couple lines.  The line causing the error is the second from the last, the call to read_graphviz.

Answer (score 2):

There is no node property named `name` in your graph, and so the property map you get from `get(boost::vertex_name, graph)` is an error.  Look at the documentation for how to add a vertex property for `boost::vertex_name` (using old-style properties) or add a bundled property to represent the name and use that instead of the `get` expression in your `dynamic_properties` object.